What situation leading to a complete sex separation fit my criteria?
Question
What situation would require modern human civilization to segregate its women and men on separate continents out of practical concerns? The women are put on Eurasia and Australia and the men on Africa and the Americas.
Considerations
For the answer:

It must not be directly about ideological, religious or cultural reasoning. No 'because their religion/culture said so'.
It shouldn't be based on negative relationships between the sexes. While interesting, I won't accept an answer like MGTOW and Feminist Separatism both succeeding on a global scale for example.
The answer needs to be relatively grounded to reality. No magic or supernatural elements but I can give some leeway to low sci-fi.
The separation must somehow be civilization's appropriate response to a problem, whatever it could be.
The separation requires men and women to have extremely minimal physical interactions. Only non-physical mediums such as the internet are accepted.
The situation demands that the separation is enforced strictly. As consequences, the arrangement shouldn't be casual, rulebreakers are heavily punished, and incentives for corruption are reduced.
The problem causing the segregation must plausibly have the potential to last for a century without humanity somehow devising a technological solution around it.
No direct, overt mind control or brainswashing. See 3.
The arbitrary continent allocations between the sexes must also be considered and incorporated into the answer. The solution must take into account why the sexes need to go to these specific locations.
Don't concern yourself with any future ramifications of your answer. I am only looking for the initial condition/s.
I will only accept the answer that integrates all of the above.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Call me slow-witted, some open doors want smashing thru here. Is segregation enforced at all time, meaning my answer must offer us an other way to procreate than traditional bedroom gymnastics? Must it explain how and when minors are segregated from other-sex parents and how, for the purposes of segregation, minors have one of the sexes assigned to them in the first place?

Disease
With the COVID pandemic, and in lesser ways with SARS, we've seen that disease can be a great motivator for drastic measures. Now this wasn't what we typically see in movies, where a disease can potentially wipe out our species in a week if the crack medical team doesn't get it's magical vaccine out the door half an hour later. Compared to popular media, COVID was mild. It still killed millions and many other lives have been temporarily or permanently altered.
If we take this to an extreme we can find a partial solution for you. One or multiple diseases are spread that are mostly harmful to a single gender. Think of a super HPV virus that is near certain to cause cancer for women, but men are largely unaffected. Or a special case of mumps. Normally there is a very rare chance men can get infertile. What if we increase it to 50%? It would lead to mass panic and a drastic change like separation is one of the options. Separation like you suggest is always incredibly unlikely to hapen, regardless of the reason, but this gives at least a semi-plausible reason for it. Whether it is mass death, becoming infertile or the 'tiny dick virus', governments will be willing for drastic measures.
Separation to islands
You can't rely on people to do all the work. I mean everybody knows disease is lurking around the corner, but that hotty just arrived and it has been a long time. Or you don't believe in the disease. To prevent this you separate them by an ocean. You make it so incredibly difficult for casual contact or very motivated people that the only solution is the proper channels. That way you have a better grip on the disease, while still being able to get the population to maintain itself.
Improved health care
There is a problem with disease with your request. Like we've seen with COVID, we got vaccines and the like fast. It would never be a decade. Even if left to roam free, disease often gets less bad over time. If you kill your host quickly, there is no way you can spread effectively.
But never fear, the same reason disease can be made manageable can become the terror of society. One of the great fears of immunologists is that virii and bacteria will be manufactured. The capability to receive viral DNA and modify it has become relatively easy, and can become more easy in the future. Someone is strategically adapting and spreading the disease to keep the separation happening. A small group with the right setup and knowledge could conceivably keep it up for a century, introducing new strains or fully new disease to one side of the population, which doesn't affect them much and can be carriers, but is extremely harmful to the other gender.

the problem is the islands are seperated by gender not sex, so a biological diffrence will not work.

@John English is not my first language, so I didn't know there was much difference between either. That being said, there is a request of separation of sexes. Sexes is mentioned 3 times, while gender only 2. From the context a sexes separation seems more logical as well than a gender separation. What do you do with anyone who doesn't identify as 'man' or 'woman'? Edit: OP has clarified sex in the title now as well.

The seperation is writen as based on gender, sex is only mention in things it can't be based on. The OP is changing the question to clarifiy, so I'll retract the downvote, but I can't change it unless you edit because it has been too long. As a side not you still have the problem of people who don't fall neatly into either sex.

@John very true. Though I think the people who can't be placed in either category man or woman are negligible, while the ones not falling in either gender is a more sizable chunk, though possibly still negligible.

the other problem with gender is not every culture defines them the same way, in some tribal cultures for instance gender is based on whether it is you or your partner who go hunting. In another they have 5 genders, one is just children. As I said I will retract the donvote, but you have to edit somthing just because the vote is time locked.

As long as the Super Cuties Virus is totally lethal to one sex and all/most of the other sex is a an asymptomatic carrier, the society will quickly be on board with the separation. If only some girls can give you Cuties, and then you might die, some brave/horny men will still try to breach quarantine. If ALL girls give you 100% fatal Cuties, then every quarantine-violator would die, until only sensible men are left.

These are kind of difficult criteria to meet - like realistically you might have nothing as a segregation of that scale introduces a ridiculous number of problems... consider the amount of effort that went into racial segregation, for example, and understand that this was still only at a very small level, mainly urban with some larger trends. Continents is a big ask if you want total purity.
My only suggestion here is some kind of disease which is harmless to one sex and very harmful to the other, and which exists passively in the unaffected sex at extremely high rates.
As it stands though, I still think such aggressive separation is unusual. Humans do have some proneness to ideologically turning against the unfamiliar, so I can see a scenario where prolonged separation could sour each sex's outlook on the other and reinforce a greater degree of separation. The other thing that needs addressing is, where are the babies coming from and going to? Population needs to be replaced, after all. And why such stark separations? The human migration required would be immense, and it makes more sense to me that things would be fractional - this part of city A and the surrounding countryside, then the other side of the river and a few small villages... this plateau... You would need a situation where borders need to be made as short and controlled as possible as well, for anything like what you've described to take place.

For the record, @Dmyt, this is the only answer I could come up with - the one that could meet all your expectations but #10. Cheers, Max.

Thanks! I'm kind of curious, though, what this scenario is even for.

@Dmyt has been developing a story about hive minds kinda taking over Earth.

Interesting! (Also, dang, do you know a lot of users' projects by now simply from the questions they ask?)

The Disease Scenario kinda solves most of those problems though.  If say, women carried 100% fatal Cuties that are harmless to the female sex but definitely kill anyone with a Y chromosome, then within years most men would die, civilization would partially collapse, and most women would die as well. I would be surprised if after a decade, there were more than a million men worldwide, and more than 10 million women, at which point the relocation effort is far easier.

This scenario could be imposed as a drastic response to a serious human overpopulation problem.  By separating males from females, this is the only way that all unplanned pregnancies could be prevented.  Without separation, measures such as sterilization or abortion might be necessary to control population, and these would be seen as more medically invasive than just physically separating males from females.
There would be a need to allow for some births, and these could be allowed by designating certain areas as mixed-gender, where those who are being allowed to reproduce could go to breed and raise their offspring.  Since women will be in Eurasia (and Australia) and men will be in Africa (and the Americas), the breeding centres could be set up on the Sinai peninsula or the Diomede or St Lawrence Islands in the Bering Strait, which are all relatively small, inhospitable places that would be possible to secure against men and women attempting to meet physically without authorisation, and allow them to get there without having to travel any great distance from a male-only area to a female-only area by air or sea.
All overseas travel for males or females authorised to reproduce could be between male-only areas (Africa <-> Americas) or female-only areas (Australia <-> Eurasia) and then by land to the breeding area in the Sinai.  By restricting air or sea travel, it should be possible to reduce the effort of quarantining males from females.  The connection of Africa to the Americas for men could take place between Natal, Brazil and Freetown, Sierra Leone, and the connection of Australia to Eurasia for women could be via the Torres Strait, New Guinea and Indonesia to Malaysia.
Given the wide separation of these overseas routes, women would have no business travelling from the Americas to Africa, and men would have no business travelling from Australia to Malaysia.

@John Do you know that the OP meant to seperate by identified gender and not biological sex?  Besides, pre-pubescent kids can stay with their parents at the breeding centres... and the OP said to not worry abuit future ramifications (#10).

see my comments up top, the OP has clarified it. Originally it said gender and they used the gender tag.

why have the breeding centres at all? Shipping cooled cups of semen around is far cheaper, faster, safer, and allows you more control, including pretty easy way to conduct mass Eugenics. Sex is fun and all, but a terribly inefficient way to transfer sperm across the globe.

@GoingDurden
Which could be a really interesting end result! Whoever's in charge might decide to keep the present arrangement so they could perform mass eugenics even after a better solution is reached. Sounds like a fun plot point.

@MaxBird, mass eugenics would happen anyway, immediately, whether they wanted or not. Due to logistics, only a handful of men/sperm could be transported around, and logically, the best would be chosen. Same on the opposite end, you only have the practical means to impregnate a tiny handful of wannabe mothers, so it only makes sense to pick the best/healthiest.
Its not possible otherwise, becuase the medical personnel/handlers would have to almsot outnumber their charges to make "free breeding" practical, and this cannot be the case, since the handlers are humans as well.

@GoingDurden Humans do have a sort of obsession over fairness and in general don't like eugenics... so I could also see a program where random selection was implemented just to remove bias and keep good genetic diversity.
Anyways, I'm talking more about the covert and deliberate continuation of the problem to keep a eugenics program going even after it's no longer strictly necessary, i.e. (going off the disease idea), a cure is found; those in power might quiet or cover up such a discovery so they could continue to tend to the genetic pool as they saw fit.

Humans love eugenics, and practice it all the time, as long as it is not named as such. Women pick tall and strong men? Eugenics. Men preferring curvy women? Eugenics. Abortion of fetuses with Downs Syndrome? Eugenics. Smart lawyers marrying smart doctors and then having intelligent kids? Eugenics. Even providing welfare to people with a lot of kids is a form of eugenics/dysgenics. Hell, Tinder and OLD are more accidentally eugenic than any program from the 1950s. We cannot help playing positive genetic selection, and praise it as long as it is not called by its actual proper name.

Just need an absolute dictator who decides they need or feel like doing this. There's nothing new about some nut deciding genocide is a great idea, or killing infidels or relocating whole populations. It's been documented since biblical times.
It's unlikely to happen in a democracy or many other types of political landscapes. Dictatorships have often killed or relocated big chunks of their own populations though.
Plenty of societies even today separate the living locations of the men and women. But children usually live with the women for their first 5 or 6 years before heading off to live with the men. This is going to be a problem for you unless you don't want children to happen. There's good reasons why women and not men throughout time have been the primary caregivers to children.
